# Problem in Finding Resource File in Android

Tags: android-layout

Hi i am using Google Maps in a code

This is the code written in the activity file

---

```
package com.hellomaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview); 
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

```
}
```

---

Now in the line setContentView(R.layout.main) it does not recognse "R" and hence mapview cannot be used in the activity as it doesnot recognse the view

I know android.R and com.google.R should not be imported.

i am stuck here .. kindly help..!!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

R file is generated when you compile your project. So if you are using eclipse just press ctrl+b and R file should appear in gen folder in your project.

If you checked out project from SVN or some other version control you could have problem with R file. If you do, create new android project in eclipse then copy/paste source and resources from checked out project to new created one and build. Hope this helps.